# k3b needs sg module loaded

Tags: kernel, boot, slackware, module

I found that I need to have the `sg` module loaded for `k3b` to work in slackware64-current.
The following command works to load it:

```
modprobe sg
```

So I want to have that module load each time I reboot.  I read that I have to modify the file `/etc/modules` and add a line for `sg`.  I do not have that file currently, not sure if I should create it.  Also read that `/etc/rc.d/rd.modules` is the file to edit in some distros.  How do I make this module start every boot?  What file do I edit, or create, and what exactly do I put in it?

Comment: I looked at the /etc/group file  and cdrom group had no members so I added root and steve as users on that line, then instructed k3b to use the cdrom group.  I know k3b recognizes the drive as it has the correct name in settings, and the menu has "eject" under "device" and it opens the dvd drive.  first i need to solve the sg problem, then I can look at the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with Slackware, I would look at

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.modules.local
```